# Forgot password sending mail in php

Tags: php, mailer

This is my forgot password code.. it works charmly when i tested it. it adds the new password to database. but it's not sending new password mail to the user

can anyone help me with this issue? it will be much helpful.

```
<?php
   function generateRandomString($length = 15) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

include 'config.php';

$check=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'"));

        if($check==1)
        {
            $users=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'"));
            $code=generateRandomString();
            $msg='Hy, '.$users['name'].' Your New Generated Password is: '.$code.'';
            $headers = "[Reset Password]";
            $mml($_POST['email'],'Reset Password',$msg,$headers);

            if($mml){
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET password='".md5($code)."' where email='".$_POST['email']."'");

            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                      <strong>New Password Has Been Sent to Your Mail!</strong> Check Your Inbox.
                    </div>';} else {
echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">
                      <strong>Timeout, Try again later!</strong>.
                    </div>';
}

        } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                              <strong>User not found!</strong>.
                            </div>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: I don't see the `mail()` function. I see you attempting to use `$mml` as a mail function, but I don't see `$mml` defined at all.

Comment: if you can help me with the changes it would be much helpful.. that `$mml`  came with the template.

Comment: @WEBFOX, you just need to call `mail()` with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: @AlexBarker i'm new to coding and i'm just started to learn. can you pinpoint and change the code which should be changed to work? it would be much helpful. i tried every possible arguments like mail and some other thing from web. but it changes password in database but not sending mail.

Comment: @WEBFOX, somewhere before `<strong>New Password Has Been Sent to Your Mail!</strong>` put a call to the built in function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.  It only takes 3 required arguments: the email to send to, the subject of said email and the body.

Comment: IDK what this `$mml` is, but it can be `$mml = mail(...)` with the same arguments

Comment: i tried this `mail($_POST['email'],'Reset Password',$msg,$headers);`  `if(mail){
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET password='".md5($code)."' where email='".$_POST['email']."'");` but it didn't work

Comment: `mail()` is a function, not a true/false variable. It does return a boolean, so you can do as Alex suggested.

Comment: then if i need to remove that second if (mail) then how the user knows he entered a correct email address. bcoz if i removed that it wont show  the success or failed message. as i said i'm noob i can't understand the words he said so can you help me to change it

Comment: Just going to pop in and mention: there are a number of security concerns with this approach. For one, email is **never** a secure means of communication. Never send passwords over email, as there's no guarantee the user will actually update it. You should instead email a one-time-use link the user can use to update their password on your site. Second, `md5` is not a secure hash function. See the [best practice guide on password storage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: Your code also appears to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You really should use prepared statements. Looks like you're saved here by the additional checks, but other parts of your app's logic are probably similar.

Comment: @Bytewave im a noob brother. this script was written by a developer who's not helping me anymore after i bought the script from him. im totally down with this forgotten password issue

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have a number of problems. As the comments suggest you are not calling the actual mail() function at all currently.

The mail() function takes a number of arguments and can have a number of issues with mail actually getting delivered if not constructed correctly.

This line:

```
 $mml($_POST['email'],'Reset Password',$msg,$headers);
```

Should be:

```
 $mnl = mail($_POST['email'],'Reset Password',$msg,$headers);
```

This will mean you will get a boolean of true/false if the FUNCTION succeded. (This does not necessarily mean your mail will get where it needs to go...) To ensure you're mail is actually going to get where it is intended you need to make sure your headers are all constructed correctly and on top of this that your DNS records are configured correctly (DKIM, SPF etc.)

Consider the following code snippet:

```
    $hostname       = "yourhostname.org";
    $date           = date('r', time());
    $nameto         = "Mr. Target";
    $recipient      = "target@targetdomain.com";
    $from           = "origin_address@yourdomain.net";
    $namefrom       = "Mr. Sender";
    $subject        = "Password Reset Thingy";

    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    //  $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
    $headers[] = "From: $namefrom <$from>";
    $headers[] = "Sender: $namefrom <$from>";
    //  $headers[] = "Bcc: Some Other Dude <me@mydomain.net>";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: $namefrom <$from>";
    $headers[] = "To: $nameto <$recipient>";
    $headers[] = "Subject: $subject";
    $headers[] = "Message-ID: <". sha1(microtime(true)) ."@$hostname>"; //This is essential for getting to Gmail addresses.... 
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    $headers[] = "Date: $date";
    $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

    $mnl = mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f $from") ;
```

So including the -f switch in the mail function is important (to force it to send), also the headers need to be constructed in as much detail as possible to avoid getting picked up by spam filters. You will have to read up in your own time about proper header construction it's beyond the scope of what I am willing to type out here.

PHP's mail function is finicky in general however, you could look at using PHPMailer as a class which makes a lot of this stuff much easier.

Or you could look at using sockets or something and write your own function to send it using SMTP which is what I do sometimes, the following function is what I usually use if the chips are down and will give you at least a starting point to work from....

```
    function authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $headers, $message) {


$smtpServer = "mail.yourhostname.com";
$port = "25"; //Or whatever the default port on your server is
$timeout = "30";
$username = "origin@yourdomain.com";
$password = "myemailpassword";
$localhost = "yourhostname.com";
$newLine = "\r\n";
$date = date('r', time()); 


    //Connect to the host on the specified port
$smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
if(empty($smtpConnect)) {
    $output = "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";
    return $output;
} else {
    $logArray['connection'] = "Connected: $smtpResponse";
}

   //Request Auth Login
fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['authrequest'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Send username
fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($username) . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['authusername'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Send password
fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($password) . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['authpassword'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Say Hello to SMTP
fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO $localhost" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['heloresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Email From
fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: $from" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['mailfromresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Email To
fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: $to" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['mailtoresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //The Email
fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['data1response'] = "$smtpResponse";

fputs($smtpConnect, "To: $to\nFrom: $from\nSubject: $subject\n$headers\n\n$message\n.\n");
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['data2response'] = "$smtpResponse";

     // Say Bye to SMTP
fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['quitresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Show log
//  echo "<pre>$to<br/>";
//  print_r ($logArray);
//  echo "</pre><hr />";
    $output = $logArray;
    return $output;
}
```

And then you can call it like so:

```
$result=authSendEmail($from,$fname,$to,$nameto,$subject,$headers,$message) ; //Use SMTP
var_dump($result);
```

Hope this helps you in some way shape or form!

Comment: i'm really sorry to waste your time i used your code and altered some but now the db is not getting update with new password and mail is also not moving to user. can i send you that reset php file can you edit that. like --enterhere--  --Change this--. it will be much helpful. i'm doing this for 2 days and cant find a solution.

Comment: Yeah dude go ahead. I'm not going to actually do it for you but I will write you a few points and you can go and read up on what I'm talking about and change it around yourself